# How do you receive Whatsapp messages from Twilio using Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, whatsapp

I am trying to build a Whatsapp chatbot using Node.JS and am running into a bit of trouble in receiving the Whatsapp message from Twilio. On checking the debugger, I get a Bad Gateway error, ie. Error 11200: HTTP Retrieval Failure. The message is getting sent, and ngrok shows the post request, however, dialogflow does not receive the request. On terminal, the error is showing UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 3 INVALID ARGUMENT: Input text not set. I'm not sure if it's because the message is not in JSON format. Please help!

This is the app.post function:

```
app.post('/api/whatsapp_query', async (req, res) =>{
        message = req.body;
        chatbot.textQuery(message.body, message.parameters).then(result => {
            twilio.sendMessage(message.from, message.to, result.fulfillmentText).then(result => {
                console.log(result);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error("Error is: ", error);
            });
            return response.status(200).send("Success");
        })
    });
```

And this is the sendMessage function I've imported:

```
const config = require('./config/keys');

const twilioAccountID = config.twilioAccountID;
const twilioAuthToken = config.twilioAuthToken;
const myPhoneNumber = config.myPhoneNumber;

const client = require('twilio')(twilioAccountID,twilioAuthToken);

module.exports = {
    sendMessage: async function(to, from, body) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            client.messages.create({
                to,
                from,
                body
            }).then(message => {
                resolve(message.sid);
            }).catch(error => {
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

And this is the textQuery function I've imported:

```
textQuery: async function(text, parameters = {}) {
        let self = module.exports;
        const request = {
            session: sessionPath,
            queryInput: {
                text: {
                    text: text,
                    languageCode: config.dialogFlowSessionLanguageCode
                },
            },
            queryParams: {
                payload: {
                    date: parameters
                }
            }
        };
        let responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
        responses = await self.handleAction(responses)
        return responses[0].queryResult;
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The issue is that you are not passing the correct message body from the incoming WhatsApp message to your `textQuery` function.

First, you should make sure that you are treating the incoming webhook from Twilio as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If you are using body-parser, ensure you have urlencoded parsing turned on.

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

Secondly, the parameters that Twilio sends start with a capital letter. So your code currently gets `message = req.body` and then uses `message.body`. But it should be `message.Body`.

Those two points should sort you out.

One final thing though. The Twilio Node.js library will return a Promise if you do not pass a callback function. So you don't need to create a Promise here:

```js
module.exports = {
    sendMessage: async function(to, from, body) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            client.messages.create({
                to,
                from,
                body
            }).then(message => {
                resolve(message.sid);
            }).catch(error => {
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

You can just return the result of the call to `client.messages.create`

```js
module.exports = {
    sendMessage: async function(to, from, body) {
        return client.messages.create({ to, from, body });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.